# How to cut the last 5 strings in one particular column for all rows

Tags: columns, cut

I have a file with multiple columns and rows, and I need to cut the last 5 strings of my third column and print it in an extra column.
For example:

```
1 info1 AAAAAAAAAAA
2 info23 TTTTTTTTTT
3 ingo45  ATATATATATATAT
4 info67 GGGYYYYUUUUUUU
```

My output will be:

```
1 info1 AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAA
2 info23 TTTTTTTTTT TTTTT
3 ingo45  ATATATATATATAT TATAT
4 info67 GGGYYYYUUUUUUU UUUUU
```

I was able to cut just the third column only by:

```
cat input_file | cut -f3 | grep -o '.\{5\}$' > output_file
```

But I want to maintain my original table. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short **`AWK`** approaches:

```
awk '{ $(NF+1)=substr($NF, length($NF)-4) }1' input-file
```

- `$NF` - the last field value
- `$(NF+1)` - becomes the last field (following the initial last field `$NF`)
- `length($NF)-4` - obtaining the starting position/offset for the **5**-character slice

---

The output:

```
1 info1 AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAA
2 info23 TTTTTTTTTT TTTTT
3 ingo45 ATATATATATATAT TATAT
4 info67 GGGYYYYUUUUUUU UUUUU
```

**----------**

The same can be reached via string substitution:

```
awk '{ sub(/.{5}$/, "& &") }1' input-file
```

- `/.{5}$/` - match the last 5 chars at the end of the record
- `&` - points to the whole matched sequence

Comment: The first solution is perfect, because sometimes I have less than 5 strings for some rows, and using the second suggestion the output was mixed between different columns when I have less than 5 strings. Thanks for the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Using two instances of the sed `&` replacement string:

```
$ sed 's/.\{5\}$/& &/' file
1 info1 AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAA
2 info23 TTTTTTTTTT TTTTT
3 ingo45  ATATATATATATAT TATAT
4 info67 GGGYYYYUUUUUUU UUUUU
```